# How can I monitor the resource consumption of a specific service for an entire month in Prometheus

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, grafana, metrics, promql

Currently, I am monitoring the service in Prometheus based on pods, which causes the data to be separated if a pod restarts or if the deployment configuration is updated. Is there a way to treat the service as a whole and display the CPU and memory consumption as a total, regardless of pod restarts or changes in deployment (or other kind) configurations?

I just want to have a final display of the total CPU and memory consumption.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Are you already using Kubernetes [Metrics Server](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/metrics-server) ?

You can monitor your service as a whole and get an aggregated view of CPU and memory consumption with Metrics Server like in our case.

Answer (score 0):

As @Saifeddine Rajhi suggested, the Kubernetes Metrics Server is a resource metrics monitoring tool for Kubernetes and it measures CPU and memory usage across the Kubernetes cluster. This metrics-server collects metrics and then shows resource usage statistics for your cluster so that you can monitor resource usage for each node and also for each pod.

To install k8 Metric server run the below command:

```
kubectl apply -f https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/metrics-server/releases/latest/download/components.yaml
```

To get the stats about your resources, you just need to run these commands. To monitor the resources of your nodes:

```
kubectl top nodes
```

To monitor the resource of your pods:

```
kubectl top pods
```

Refer to this [blog](https://signoz.io/blog/kubernetes-metrics-server/) written by Ezz EI Din Abdullah for more information.

You can use:

`sum(rate(container_cpu_usage_seconds_total{pod="pod name",container="container name"}[5m])) by (container)`,

`sum(container_memory_working_set_bytes{{pod="pod name",container="container name"}[5m])) by (container)`  to get the sum of all the pods (replicas) CPU and memory usage belonging to one particular service.

Comment: I can now monitor the CPU and memory of pods and nodes. My requirement is to display CPU and memory based on services. For example, if a deployment has 4 replicas, I want to monitor these 4 pods as a whole. If I only monitor individual pods, the names will be updated when pods are restarted or updated, making it impossible to collect data as a whole.

Comment: Have you tried creating custom PromQL queries that sum the CPU and memory metrics for all the pods? Refer to this SO [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62770744) which can be helpful in resolving the issue.

Comment: My intention is to resolve this problem using PromQL as well. However, I haven't been able to find a suitable approach for aggregating CPU and memory based on services. The solution mentioned in the link is based on the entire namespace.

Comment: I have upadated my answer. You can also refer to this [link](https://www.weave.works/blog/aggregating-pod-resource-cpu-memory-usage-arbitrary-labels-prometheus/). Let me know if that helps.